# Access denied when copying embedded resource

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, access-denied

I have a .exe file as an embedded resource named `IDMan.exe` in my c# project. I want it to be copied in `D:\` directory. i have the following code

```
public static void extractResource(String embeddedFileName, String destinationPath)
{
   Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   string[] arrResources = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
   foreach (string resourceName in arrResources)
   if (resourceName.ToUpper().EndsWith(embeddedFileName.ToUpper()))
   {
       Stream resourceToSave = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
       var output = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath);
       resourceToSave.CopyTo(output);
       resourceToSave.Close();
    }
}
```

But whatever directory I choose it says

> Access to path 'D:\' is Denied.

Comment: Probably, your application doesn't have appropriate permissions. You can try to run your application as administrator.

Comment: Did that already. Its gives the same exception error.

Comment: Also when run from IDE in debugging mode same error